# Redirect to a specific part of the page with a link

Tags: html, hyperlink

This is my link to the specific page from another page.

```
<a href="http://test.com/#test"
```

and this is my part of page I want to display but it does not work...

```
<div id="test"><h4>Title of test</h4></div>
```

I am using WordPress, could it cause the problem?

Comment: I assume your full link is like this? `<a href="http://test.com/#test"> Some content </a>`

Comment: Have you tried using `<a name="test" id="test"><h4>Title...` instead?

Comment: Yes, it is. I got redirecred all the time but to the top of the page...

Comment: Are you trying to link to another page, or are do you want to anchor to another section of the same page?

Comment: I am trying to link to another page

Comment: It does not work, I already tried it

Comment: Then it's most likely due to some JavaScript you use on the page. Try disabling all JavaScript and see if it works.

Comment: If I disable javascript the I will get the whole white page probably because of wordpress plugin page builder

Comment: Don't view the page as an admin.

Comment: I really don't view that page as admin... I am totally mad of this link...

Comment: You're seeing the page builder, because you're logged in.

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
<div id="test">
  <h4>
    Title of test
  </h4>
</div>
```

to this...

```
<a name="test">
  <h4> 
    Title of test
  </h4>
</a>
```

You should be able to link to it with this:

```
<a href="http://test.com/test-page#test">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can jump to a specific page section by using an anchor tag with a name or id attribute, like:

`<a id="test"><h4>Title of test</h4></a>` 
or 
`<a name="test"><h4>Title of test</h4></a>`

Actually, it looks like name was only for HTML4, ID is what should be used for HTML5 per here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name

Comment: If you cannot post the website, at least post more information about what you've tried including the actual code.  I have used id="test" often in my websites without issue, so perhaps there is something small that you are not seeing.

Comment: Yes, I usually use that without issue too but now there is... I am editting wordpress theme where the index page is divided to six sections and my links works on this page they scroll me down to the specific section. But when I am at child page It does not scroll or show the specific section... It all the time shows top of the page